# Does this text have non-standard Italian?

Tags: spelling

I don't speak Italian, and my knowledge of Italian is limited to the amount I have learned through being a musician (so, mostly single words, with little grammatical context, I'm afraid!)

I have been asked to transcribe sheet music for the following song:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HJ6izQgsTs

I have also been given the following text for the song's lyrics:

> Firenze bella,
>   quando riposi placida e tranquilla,
>   il Campanil di Giotto è sentinella
>   e in ogni cuore accendi una scintilla.
>
> Oggi per te, oh Firenze, col mio cantare,
>   come cantava il paggio sotto i veroni,
>   non vuoi sentir le musiche d’oltre mare
>   ma vuoi sentir soltanto le tue canzoni.
>
> Oggi ritorni serra di mille fiori
>   mentre Boccaccio narra gli antichi amori.
>
> Fior di verbena,
>   l’arco dell’ar l’è tutta porporina,
>   il menestrello canta la sua pena
>   a una bella madonna fiorentina.
>
> Mentre lontano muoion le serenate
>   e la Maremma è tutta colori e fiori,
>   cantano ancor le rondini innamorate
>   e con i fiori sbocciano mille amori.
>
> Fiesole si ridesta col primo sole
>   ma non si spegne l’eco delle mandole.
>
> Oh Fiorentina,
>   è la tua bocca una sorgente arcana
>   cinta da una collana alabastrina,
>   sono assetato e cerco una fontana.
>
> Firenze bella!

I have been using online sources to help with checking spelling and how to hyphenate the syllables, but I am not able to find some of the words. I just wondered if there is any non-standard Italian in here.

I will be asking Italian speaking colleagues to check through what I've done, but I wanted to be proactive, and try to work out as much as I can myself first.

Comment: For anybody who's interested, I posted this related question on Music.SE (as I know posting the same question on different SE sites is frowned upon...) https://music.stackexchange.com/q/56334/9198

Comment: @BobBroadley In case you are interested, the "blur" you refer in the related question is a standard feature of Italian phonology and it is called [Synalepha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synalepha).

Comment: I think I've learnt more today than any other day for years. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is standard Italian, although some passage are in a "poetic" language (uncommon word order, some truncations or archaisms).

The only word that's leaving me a little bit puzzled is *ar*, which could be a truncation of *aria* but which I don't think I've ever heard (in poetry the more archaic *aer* would sound more natural). Listening carefully to the song, it sounds like the singer is saying *l'acqua dell'Arno* instead of *l'arco dell'ar*, which would make a lot more sense (thanks to @DaG for pointing me on the right direction). All things considered, I think the lyrics you have are wrong, and that the singer is saying

> l'acqua dell'Arno è tutta porporina,

If you are having difficulties with  some words, please ask a separate question where we might be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks, Denis! Yes, "dell'ar" was causing me the most problems searching online - I just managed to find a lot of pages about Dell in Arkansas!

Comment: Listening to the song, it might just be “L'arco dell'Arno è tutto porporina”. What do you think, Denis?

Comment: @DaG Listening carefully it sounds like the singer is saying *l'acqua dell'Arno è tutta porporina* which would make much more sense. Do you agree with me?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right, Denis.

Comment: I agree with @Denis: listening to the video, it seems to me that the singer is saying *l'acqua dell'Arno è tutta porporina*.